# Converting C assign/conditional statement to C#

Tags: c#, c, translation

I am translating some code from C to C#. I'm not sure how best to translate the following 2 lines:

```
if (tt = v >> 16)
{
    r = (t = tt >> 8) ? 24 + LT[t] : 16 + LT[tt];
}
```

tt, v, and t are ulongs (not really relevant to the problem). The problem is I don't think C# allows the assign/conditional operation in one statement.

In C#, one cannot implicitly convert from ulong to bool. The following line doesn't compile either:

```
if ((bool)(tt = v >> 16))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the one for your `if` statement.

```
(tt = v >> 16) != 0
```

You cant easily cast an `int` to a `bool`.

Comment: Thank guys. From your posts, I got the following as the most compact representation: if ((tt = v >> 16) != 0)

Answer (score 2):

This is a direct conversion:

```
tt = v >> 16;
if (tt != 0) {
    t = tt >> 8;
    r = (t != 0) ? 24 + LT[t] : 16 + LT[tt];
}
```

Generally speaking, terse C code doesn't look good when converted to C#. I suggest making it a little bit more verbose to make life easier in the future. (Call me biased, but it takes a lot more to frighten people used to C than those using newer languages).

Comment: I agree with you on the frigthen part ;)
I think "if ((tt = v >> 16) != 0)" is readable. But I do agree too that directly translated terse C can be awkward in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tt = v >> 16;
if (tt != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This shoud  simply work:

```
tt = v >> 16;
if (tt != 0)
{
    t = tt >> 8;
    r = (t != 0) ? 24 + LT[t] : 16 + LT[tt];
}
```

Comment: -1: - what about negative numbers in the case its not a `ulong`?

Comment: @Daniel A. White : well OP said its a `ulong` however i have edited my code. Thanx for suggestion :)